# Improve performance of sunrise/sunset calculations in Skyfield

Tags: python, skyfield

Given coordinates (lat/lon) and timestamps, I'm computing for each coordinate/timestamp pair whether the sun is up at that location and time using the [`skyfield`](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) library:

```py
import datetime as dt

import numpy as np
from skyfield import almanac
from skyfield.api import Loader
from skyfield.toposlib import wgs84
from skyfield_data import get_skyfield_data_path


load = Loader(get_skyfield_data_path())
eph = load("de421.bsp")
ts = load.timescale()

# Made up times
datetimes = [
    dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1, tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc)
    + dt.timedelta(minutes=m) for m in range(24 * 60)
]
times = ts.from_datetimes(datetimes)

# Made up coordinates
coordinates = np.array([
    (50.0, lon)
    for lon in np.linspace(0.0, 30.0, 1000)
])

results = []
for lat, lon in coordinates:
    pos = wgs84.latlon(lat, lon)
    is_day = almanac.sunrise_sunset(eph, pos)
    results.append(is_day(times))
```

This code works, but is too slow for my needs. Is there a way to move the Python-loop over the coordinates into NumPy? The Skyfield docs say that Skyfield uses NumPy, but as far as I can tell `wgs84.latlon` doesn't take a NumPy array as input.

If there's no way to avoid the Python-loop, is there perhaps a way to treat some accuracy for speed?

Note that in my real use case both the timestamps and the coordinates are user-provided and unknown in advance, so I cannot assume they have any specific structure.

Comment: With slow what do you mean? Minutes? hours? And how many calculations you want to do?

Comment: @MSH: The example I posted currently takes around 20s on my machine. I don't have a particular performance goal ("that many calculations in this time"), but this is a bottleneck in a bigger piece of code that I would like to improve.

Comment: So my answer (below) that runs in 3 seconds isn't a satisfactory improvement over the 20 second run time that you report? Odd

Comment: @BrutusForcus: As I commented on your answer: my actual code is part of a larger code base which already uses various parallelization methods, among them multiprocessing computation. That is, the code already runs in a multiprocessed way that is managed on a higher architectural level, and it cannot simply spawn new processes on its own. Therefore, as stated in the question, I'm looking for approaches that move work from the (slow) Python loop to (fast) C/NumPy loops or that trade run time for accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing is a common solution for CPU intensive activities: which this appears to be.

*eph* cannot be shared across multiple processes due to pickling errors. That means that each process will have to call *load()*. However, that appears to be relatively fast. The following code runs in ~3s on my machine. That may or may not be better than your current experience as the duration of execution isn't mentioned in your original question.

```
import time
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
from skyfield import almanac
from skyfield.api import Loader
from skyfield.toposlib import wgs84
from skyfield_data import get_skyfield_data_path
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


load = Loader(get_skyfield_data_path())

ts = load.timescale()

# Made up times
datetimes = [
    dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1, tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc)
    + dt.timedelta(minutes=m) for m in range(24 * 60)
]
times = ts.from_datetimes(datetimes)

# Made up coordinates
coordinates = np.array([
    (50.0, lon)
    for lon in np.linspace(0.0, 30.0, 1000)
])


def docalc(lat, lon):
    pos = wgs84.latlon(lat, lon)
    eph = load('de421.bsp')
    return almanac.sunrise_sunset(eph, pos)(times)


def main():
    results = []
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = []
        for lat, lon in coordinates:
            futures.append(executor.submit(docalc, lat, lon))
        for future in futures:
            results.append(future.result())
    return results


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = time.perf_counter()
    main()
    e = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Duration = {e-s:.4f}s')
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'm aware of external approaches to improve performance, like multiprocessing, and those are already used in the software in which I'm using Skyfield. Hence I'm looking for performance optimizations that are directly linked to Skyfield, e.g. leveraging its NumPy support.